# Using createDate in the REST API

Tags: rest-api, datetime, chatter-feed-tracking

I'm just curious if there is a way to use `between` in the the REST api?

Something like

```
curl -v https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v27.0/chatter/feed-items/me/comments -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00Di0000000Co-e'
```

I saw `?since=2%3A1344352279000` in the [REST API Resources](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resources_how_to.htm#cc_filter_resources) if you look under Poll Feeds.

Can we use isModified for items other than polls? Is this using a *nix timestamp?

**UPDATE**

trying to curl with `/chatter/feeds/news/me/is-modified?since=2%3A1344352279000` gives me a restricted response =( Atleast this seems theoretically possible on some of the RESTful endpoints now.

Here's the return resp:

```
{
  "0":{
    "message":"You do not have permission to execute that operation.",
    "errorCode":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS"
  },
  "last":"/"
  "GET":"/chatter/feeds/news/me/is-modified?since=2%3A1344352279000"
}
```

This does not seem to work on `/chatter/feeds/to/me`

which returns:

```
{
  "0":{
    "message":"The requested resource does not exist",
    "errorCode":"NOT_FOUND"
  },
  "last":"/"
  "GET":"/chatter/feeds/to/me/is-modified?since=2%3A1344352279000"
}
```

Comment: docs state that this is a token, not an actual date/time stamp. Have you tried playing with the REST explorer on workbench.developerforce.com?

Comment: Yeah I actually wrote my own, which is what I'm using now. what I'm currently having to do is find a time quantifier in a response, and find the difference between unix timestamps =( its yuck.